# PSExec tool using without authenticating to clients on same subnet

Tags: windows, networking, nat

If I am using VirtualBox NAT virtual networking, will I be able to execute programs on another host in my subnet without authenticating?

Comment: The fact that the client is a VM is irrelevant.  So is the NAT.  All that matters is the relationship between the client and the host.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought the question is whether you are authenticated on the remote PC. ie are your local/current credentials valid on the remote machine. For example if both the virtual box machine and the remote are in an active directory and you are logged on and authenticated (for both) then, yes but if you are running a VM as a local user only, with no network credentials, then no, you will have to authenticate on the remote.